# Response Redirect on a different site

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this path for my application:

```
computername.com/Site1
```

I have a dropdown that when the value is changed, it should redirect the website to this:

```
computername.com/Site2
```

My problem here is that when I do this

```
string url = string.Format("computername.com/" + dropDownValue);
Response.Redirect(url);
```

I get redirected to `computername.com/Site1/computername.com/Site2`

What method can I do to achieve the behavior that I wanted?

Thanks!

Comment: add http:// in front of it

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
string url = string.Format("http://computername.com/" + dropDownValue);
Response.Redirect(url);
```

That happens because your previously constructed URL recognized as relative rather than absolute.